# Survival analysis no one failed during the period of the study

Tags: survival, cox-model

I'm trying to analyze data where I found that no one failed during the period of the study. This is the Error I got, as I gave the command.

```
> fitsurv <- coxph(Surv(NumSessions, failed) ~ o + a + n + c + e, data=records)
Error in fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : 
 NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning message:
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
 Ran out of iterations and did not converge
```

is as above.

Can anyone tell me what this means?

Comment: Isn't it telling you that the survival function isn't defined in a case where all observations are censored?

Comment: If that is the case, could you tell me how to analyze such data?

Comment: What other questions do you want answered about the data? You can summarize time elapsed so far, but it is contingent on an arbitrary cut-off date. In some contexts that makes sense, e.g. as length of service of people currently in post.

Comment: It would no longer be a *survival* analysis but a multiple regression of some type, correct?

Comment: Note that your survival functions will just be 1. What are you trying to find out?

Comment: Actually I realized it was a coding error. I got the right results a while later. Thanks for all your comments!